# Would it be helpful to those looking for work to have a tag = accessibility?

Tags: discussion

Just got back from the CSUN conference in San Diego http://www.csun.edu/cod/conference/2015/sessions/index.php/public/website_pages/view/1

Lot of conversation about training developers to be able to code for accessibility. Lots of people/ companies looking for coders/ programmers with those skills.

Several mentions in the sessions of Stack Overflow being a "go to" place to talk code problems.

If you were looking for a job with those skills - accessibility coding would having them tagged that way help your search?

Answer (score 1):

Either you got it wrong, or those "several mentions" were wrong themselves in understanding what Stack Overflow really is.

Stack Overflow is **not** a place where code problems are being discussed because Stack Overflow is not a discussion board.

That said, the [accessibility tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) on Stack Overflow is kind of "meta tag" i.e. got no value of its own, and I highly doubt employers are going over the tag page to look for possible candidates.

Comment: I would think that 'accessibility' would be a tag that describes particular content and wouldn't be a meta tag.

Comment: I could be wrong with my exact identification of the site, but those several developers said they looked for coding answers to their questions on what I thought was "Stack Overflow". Maybe it was "Stack Exchange" or some other varient. Apologize if I didn't get it exactly right.

Comment: The real point of my question, to Lance's comment, is that, there are more and more jobs where the developer will be expected to build accessibility into their code. This is a skill that is on top of and different than 'Python' 'Ruby' 'CSS3' or any other kind of Tag that would ID what the coder could do.

Comment: @eliannajames that is correct, but not really relevant - employers would look in resume and ask candidates to pass tests, not look on a specific tag score.